# Nested use declarations

Tags: rust

What does the following syntax mean?

`use tokio_tungstenite::{connect_async, tungstenite::protocol::Message};`

Is it equivalent to this?

```
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async::tungstenite::protocol::Message;
```

I doubt it: `tokio_tungstenite::connect_async::tungstenite::protocol::Message` is not a symbol.

Comment: If you take out the spaces you can use shell expansion to list the things it expands to. `echo tokio_tungstenite::{connect_async,tungstenite::protocol::Message}` => `tokio_tungstenite::connect_async tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::protocol::Message`

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to:

```
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::protocol::Message;
```